# Continuous Release succeeded but website didn't change

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I successfully set up a CI/CR process for my ASP.NET website to Azure web app service. I did some changes, queued up a new build and waited for both the build and release to succeed. However, when I launch the website, I didn't see my changes. 
The release definition is like this:
[image: The release definition]

The Azure web app service is like this:
[image: Azure web app service]

I can see that the release is successful on vsts. 
[image: Release succeeded on vsts]

I can see that the release is successful on Azure.
[image: Release succeeded on Azure]

But I can't see my changes on the website. I can see the changes if I run the website locally from my Visual Studio. I am pretty sure I checked in all my changes to vsts. Did I miss some steps here?

--Updates------------------------------------

This time I checked the "Publish using Web Deploy" option like this:
[image]
But still no luck. :(

You can find the [Release log files here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xStIPOYMEDKpR0P0_dzlEKBp_XpaTO6Q?usp=sharing)

Comment: Clear cache and reload, try incognito mode.

Comment: @Nate I tried to clear cache for my browser, didn't help. What is incognito mode?

Comment: "Incognito mode" means "Private mode". Like for MicrosoftEdge, you can use "InPrivate" browser.

Comment: @SwikrutiBose Unfortunately "Private mode" is not the answer here, I just tried it, no luck.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark @NJUHOBBY

Comment: Did you check if the new changes exist in the build artifact that the release use?

Comment: I am facing the same issue did you find a solution for it? Please share with me if you resolved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting any error message when trying to access the website, share the detailed error message, which might help to resolve the issue.

Also, try to add “MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES = 1” in “Application Settings” tab for your web app and see if it helps. You may refer the below screenshot,
[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps?view=vsts.

Comment: I didn't get any error message when trying to access the website after release. Also I just checked the "Application Settings" in my app service, it already has "MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES" set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You specified the zip file in **Package or folder** input box, but don’t check **Publish using Web Deploy** option, so it just upload the zip file to web service, that’s the reason.

You need to check **Publish using Web Deploy** option if deploying with the zip file.

Update:

Refer to these steps below to publish web app:

1. Specify MSBuild Arguments in Visual Studio Build task: `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish`
2. Archive Files task (Root folder or file to archive: $(Build.artifactstagingdirectory))
3. Publish Build Artifacts

Comment: I checked the "Publish using Web Deploy" option, queued a new build, and waited for the release to succeed, but I still didn't see my changes. Please see my updates on the original post.

Comment: @NJUHOBBY Can you share detail log on the OneDrive? (Add system.debug variable with true value, then start release and share this log)

Comment: You also can check the files in app service by accessing https://{site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole (in site\wwwroot folder)

Comment: I just used Kudu to check the files on the app service. The html file that I made my changes in was not modified in the last release. Sorry I am not very familiar with vsts release, where should I add the system.debug variable to generate the detail log?

Comment: 1. Edit your release definition 2. Add system.debug variable in variables tab 3. Start release 4. In Release result page > Click Logs tab > click Download all logs as zip

Comment: Please find the release files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xStIPOYMEDKpR0P0_dzlEKBp_XpaTO6Q?usp=sharing

Comment: @NJUHOBBY Based on the log file, there isn't html file. What's the detail of your project? Can you share build log on the OneDrive?

Comment: Definitely, please find the build log files here:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RnoPx-26K9yEoSEFcbrdUzm6dRJTQfN9

Comment: Oh actually because this is a ASP.NET MVC project, it should be cshtml file, rather than html file. Sorry for the misunderstanding.. I did changes in _basicInfo.cshtml

Comment: @NJUHOBBY You don't publish your project, check the update of my answer to publish project and deploy to azure with published files.